# Update on Insert HSQLDB

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I am trying to rewrite code, that was using MySQL database, to use HSQLDB. I have an `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query. Is there an alternative of this method for HSQLDB.

Code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user_stats "
    + "(user, balance, kills, level)"
    + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY "
    + "UPDATE balance=VALUES(balance), kills=VALUES(kills), level=VALUES(level)");

ps.setString(1, playername);
ps.setDouble(2, PluginInterract.getESSBalance(playername));
ps.setInt(3, PluginInterract.getKills(playername));
ps.setDouble(4, PluginInterract.getPluginLevel(playername));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not according to [the documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_insert_statement).  The [`MERGE`](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement) statement might do what you want, however.  Here is an untested example based on the documentation for `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO user_stats USING (VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?))
    AS vals(user, balance, kills, level) ON user_stats.user = vals.user
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET user_stats.balance = vals.balance, user_stats.kills = vals.kills, user_stats.level = vals.level
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES vals.user, vals.balance, vals.kills, vals.level
```

Comment: MERGE INTO {{tablename}} USING {{ values section }} ON {{ collide condition }}
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {{ update fields }}
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES {{ add fields}}

Is it correct syntax for Merge?

Comment: I showed an example and provided a link to the documentation.  I have never used HSQLDB and I do not have an environment to test in.  You'll have to do that part yourself.

Answer (score 2):

From version 2.3.3 (June 2015) HSQLDB supports `INSERT INTO  ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` in MYS compatibility mode.

Refer: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#coc_compatibility_mysql

But version 2.3.3 doesn't support `Values(COLUMN_NAME)` method of MySQL.